# User thread spawning in Jetty

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jetty

I have a web application running over Jetty, and I need to spawn a thread for idle connection handling. This thread is being started in the spring context.

I know it's not a good practice to spawn threads in a container, but couldn't find a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the container set up a timer or thread pool for you.  See [the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html).

Comment: And HttpClientManager is a Thread? or calls Thread.start()?  I think you're better off making it a Runnable or TimerTask, and then using Spring's scheduling/pooling support.  But you might also find this to be of interest: http://denistek.blogspot.com/2008/10/spawn-thread-in-servlet.html

Comment: This might be helpful as well: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/embedded-spring-web-services.html

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way to handle such resources is in a servlet context listener.  Check the Servlet API.